# EventsCalendar not displaying correctly with jQuery Colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using jQuery EventsCalendar inside jQuery Colorbox. But the calendar is not showing fully.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#MyCalendar").eventCalendar({});
$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:295, height:335});

});
```

Html

```
<div class="choose-calendar">
      <a class='inline' href="#inline_content"><img src="images/choose_calendar.png" alt="choose calendar"></a>
      <div style='display:none'>
            <div id='inline_content' style=' background:#fff; display: list-item;'>
                 <div id="MyCalendar"></div>
            </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Is it z-index problem?  You can view at http://pfitr.net/frontend/events-calendar.html

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I could able to solve the problem by adding the following css code:

```
#MyCalendar {
width:275px;
height:270px !important;
}
```

Cheers!